# Запрос для тега

Tags: sql, data.stackexchange.com

Нужно посчитать количество пользователей, спросивших менее 2 вопросов с тегом *java*.

Пишу такой запрос:

```
SELECT DisplayName from users where DuplicateOfQuestionId < 2 from TagName = 'java'
```

для основы.

Comment: и в чем именно проблема?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: на ru.SO таких 1185, на SO больше 170к. А "запрос для основы" не годится, потому что это не запрос, а набор слов.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю как выглядит ваша схема, но запрос будет примерно такой:

```
select DisplayName, Count(TagName) as TagCount from User
  left outer join Question on User.Id = AskerId && TagName = 'java'
  group by User.Id, TagName
  having TagCount < 2
```

[Можно посмотреть этот пример на SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da594/14/0)

Comment: "Не знаю как выглядит ваша схема" - это ж про StackOverflow вопрос.